# Algorithm: Change all values of array depending on one and keeping same sum

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

**Dear all,**

I am stuck with a problem I have to solve. I'm doing it in JavaScript, but this applied generally to any language and is more an algorithm issue than anything else.

Lets say I have an array with 5 values and the TOTAL of these values should **always be 500** in the end. The start values are 100, 100, ... , 100.

Ok and now I want that for the case I change ONE value, the other values "adjust" in the way so the "total value" of 500 is kept. And they don't arrange in some random order, but keep they original position and "move" towards the balance so their original value is kept (a bit).

Example:

```
100 100 100 100 100
```

I set the first one to 0
Result should be:

```
0 125 125 125 125
```

Now I set the second to 0
Result should be:

```
31.25 0 156.25 156.25 156.25
```

I have a working prototype - but I am very unsatisfied with the results. And I believe it can be done a LOT easier, but I cant think of any.

Im attaching my JS source and its fully commented.

**Here is the general idea:**

```
INPUT:
 - array: of N INT elemnt values
 - changed: the index of the element that has been adjusted, this one will be ignored for the array adjustments
 - arrayMin / arrayMax: the values that are considered limits for the array elements
 - arraySum: defines the sum of the array - this is important to see to what SUM the array has to adjust

 PROCESS:
 - the array elements minus 1 (the one that is ignored) are counted
 - the difference made by the one change of the whole sum is computed
 - the difference that has to be made to one and each (except the changed) is computed
 - now there is a loop which adds (or subtracts) the difference to each object
 - if the object reaches its limits (min or max) nothing can be added or subtracted more and this element will be ingored for the rest computation
 - what could not be added to these elements hitting the limit is saved in REST
 - at the end the loop checks if there is any REST and if there is, the loops repeats with REST computed among elements that can and may be adjusted further
 - NOTE: If the rest is really small - treat it
```

Should anyone be interested why and what for I need it - I was thinking of **using four sliders** that share one "total" value and you set them up according to your preferences and the others take values depending on the change.

Source:
[JS source file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17524455/reMapArray.js)

**Im open to ideas :) **

**Thank you**

**Oliver**

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but I think you still have to narrow down what you think could be improved. Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the min/max constraints the function could look like this:

```js
function reMapArray(array, changed, arraySum) {
    const sum = array.reduce( (a, b) => a+b );
    const adjust = (sum - arraySum) / (array.length - 1);
    return array.map( (a, i) => i === changed ? a : a - adjust );
}
// Demo use
let array = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
array[0] = 0;
array = reMapArray(array, 0, 500);
console.log(array.toString());
array[1] = 0;
array = reMapArray(array, 1, 500);
console.log(array.toString());
```

With the min/max verification added, it could look like this:

```js
function reMapArray(array, index, minValue, maxValue, arraySum) {
    const sum = array.reduce( (a, b) => a+b );
    if (sum === arraySum) return array; // end recursion: solution found
    const adjust = (arraySum - sum) / array.reduce( 
        // count the values that can still be modified
        (c, a, i) => c + (i === index ? 0 
                        : arraySum > sum ? a < maxValue 
                        : a > minValue), 
        0);
    // apply adjustment, but without getting out of range, and then recurse
    return reMapArray(array.map( (a, i) => 
            i === index ? a : Math.max(minValue, Math.min(maxValue, a + adjust)) ),
        index, minValue, maxValue, arraySum);
}
// Demo use:
let array = [100, 100, 100, 100, 100];
array[0] = 0;
array = reMapArray(array, 0, 0, 150, 500);
console.log(array.toString());
array[1] = 0;
array = reMapArray(array, 1, 0, 150, 500);
console.log(array.toString());
```

Here the second output is different than with the first solution, because the maximum value has been set to 150, so an output with 156.25 is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the input, Ill test it for the min max and work a bit later :-) thank you though a lot! :-)

Comment: I added the min/max constraint to my answer.

Comment: Btw I love the recursive approach! :)

Comment: Glad to hear you liked it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Java solution for those interested:

```
public class ArrayAutoAdjuster {

private double[] values = new double[5];

public ArrayAutoAdjuster(){
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        values[i] = 100;
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayAutoAdjuster aaa = new ArrayAutoAdjuster();

    aaa.setNewValue(0,0);
    System.out.println(aaa.toString());
    aaa.setNewValue(1, 0);
    System.out.println(aaa.toString());


}

public void setNewValue(int position, double value){
    if(values[position] == value){
        return;
    }

    double diff = (values[position] - value)/(values.length-1);

    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        values[i] = i == position ? value : values[i] + diff;
    }
}

public String toString(){
    String s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        s += values[i];
        if(i < values.length-1){
            s+=",";
        }
    }
    return s;
}

}
```

Comment: This question was tagged with `javascript` not `java`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with some logging and error checking.

```js
var sum = function(acc, itemValue) { return acc + itemValue; };

var setInitialArray = function(numItems, total) {
  console.log("Create array of " + numItems + " items that sum to " + total);
  var itemValue = Math.floor(total / numItems);
  var extra = total - (numItems * itemValue);
  var initArray = Array.apply(null, Array(5)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, itemValue);
  initArray[0] += extra;
  return initArray;
};

var adjustArray = function(itemIdx, newValue, items) {
  if (!Number.isInteger(itemIdx) || itemIdx < 0 || itemIdx >= items.length) return items;
  console.log("Set item " + (itemIdx + 1) + " to " + newValue);
  var total = items.reduce(sum, 0),
    origItemValue = items[itemIdx],
    diffValue = origItemValue - newValue,
    totalForRemainItems = total + diffValue,
    numItems = items.length - 1;
  if (diffValue === 0 || totalForRemainItems < 0) return items;
  // make copy of items without the changing item
  var newItems = [].concat(items);
  newItems.splice(itemIdx, 1);
  var itemValue = Math.floor(totalForRemainItems / numItems);
  var extra = totalForRemainItems - (numItems * itemValue);
  newItems.forEach(function(item, idx)  { newItems[idx] = (idx === 0) ? itemValue + extra : itemValue; });
  newItems.splice(itemIdx, 0, newValue);
  return newItems;
};

var myArray = setInitialArray(5, 502);
console.log(myArray);
var myNewArray = adjustArray(2, 50, myArray);
console.log(myNewArray);
```

Comment: Ulala! Thank you :-) will check a bit later